# Полосочка жизней в браузерной игре

Tags: php, javascript

В бд есть таблица startpoke , в ней же есть столбик life. Задача нужно вывести уровень жизней в таком формате [Картинка](http://s017.radikal.ru/i413/1110/39/d0aaf53f15f7.jpg) и при этом когда жизни уменьшаются полосочка тоже стает меньше. Как это сделать ?

Comment: Самое просто средствами html + css прописывать отображение...

Comment: ну вот я и спрашиваю как это сделать =)

Comment: Вот так что ли DIV style="width:100%;background:green;height:12;font-size:9;"></DIV

Comment: Хорошо но как это сделать в процентах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<div style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>
  <div style='left:0px;width:59%;background-color:green;'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>

// на php:

echo '<div style="width:100px;border:1px solid black;">'.
     '  <div style="left:0px;width:'.$procent_of_life.'%;background-color:green;">'.
     '    &nbsp'.
     '  </div>'.
     '</div>';
```

1. **`100px`** - это задаваемая вами ширина для полоски ВСЕЙ жизни
2. **`59%`** - это процент оставшейся жизни
3. **`$procent_of_life`** - переменная со значением жизни

Высчитать процент оставшейся жизни можно так:
`round( 100 * $current_life / $max_life );`
где **`$current_life`** - текущее кол-во жизней; **`$max_life`** - максимальное кол-во жизней

Comment: АгА , я тоже так подумал и написал =) Но как это сделать в процентах?

Comment: что именно нужно в процентах?

Comment: Вот смотрите 100 жизней это сто процентов, жизни стают меньше выводить нужно и меньше =)

Comment: ну напишите width:59%; от этого ничего не изменится :)

меняя это 59% вы меняете отображаемое количество жизни.

Comment: вот смотрите, покемон побывал в бою, ему сняло 10 жизней , значит должно уже выводить не width:100% а width:90% вот как это сделать ?

Comment: То что нужно =) вы как всегда правы =)

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Через JS можно поменять width легко динамически, если ты про это.

Comment: я не знаю JS

Comment: Если само должно обновиться - то надо при ударах/иных ключевых действиях, а также в общем просто через некоторые интервалы времени AJAX'ом подгружать инфу о жизни с сервера и JS'ом менять длину.